# Pandas dataframe and character encoding when reading excel file

Tags: python, excel, character-encoding, pandas

I am reading an excel file that has several numerical and categorical data. The columns name_string contains characters in a foreign language. 
When I try to see the content of the name_string column, I get the results I want, but the foreign characters (that are displayed correctly in the excel spreadsheet) are displayed with the wrong encoding.
Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('MC_simulation.xlsx', 'DataSet', encoding='utf-8')
name_string = df.name_string.unique()
name_string.sort()
name_string
```

Producing the following:

```
array([u'4th of July', u'911', u'Abab', u'Abass', u'Abcar', u'Abced',
       u'Ceded', u'Cedes', u'Cedfus', u'Ceding', u'Cedtim', u'Cedtol',
       u'Cedxer', u'Chevrolet Corvette', u'Chuck Norris',
       u'Cristina Fern\xe1ndez de Kirchner'], dtype=object)
```

In the last line, the correctly encoded name should be Cristina Fernández de Kirchner. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, the data is being parsed correctly into [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), not `strs`. The `u` prefix indicate that the objects are `unicode`. When a list, tuple, or NumPy array is printed, Python shows the `repr` of the items in the sequence. So instead of seeing the printed version of the `unicode`, you see the `repr`:

```
In [160]: repr(u'Cristina Fern\xe1ndez de Kirchner')
Out[160]: "u'Cristina Fern\\xe1ndez de Kirchner'"

In [156]: print(u'Cristina Fern\xe1ndez de Kirchner')
Cristina Fernández de Kirchner
```

[The purpose of the `repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/190597) is to provide an unambiguous string representation for each object. The printed verson of a unicode can be ambiguous because of invisible or unprintable characters.

If you print the DataFrame or Series, however, you'll get the printed version of the unicodes:

```
In [157]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':np.array([u'4th of July', u'911', u'Abab', u'Abass', u'Abcar', u'Abced',
       u'Ceded', u'Cedes', u'Cedfus', u'Ceding', u'Cedtim', u'Cedtol',
       u'Cedxer', u'Chevrolet Corvette', u'Chuck Norris',
       u'Cristina Fern\xe1ndez de Kirchner'], dtype=object)})
   .....:    .....:    .....: 
In [158]: df
Out[158]: 
                               foo
0                      4th of July
1                              911
2                             Abab
3                            Abass
4                            Abcar
5                            Abced
6                            Ceded
7                            Cedes
8                           Cedfus
9                           Ceding
10                          Cedtim
11                          Cedtol
12                          Cedxer
13              Chevrolet Corvette
14                    Chuck Norris
15  Cristina Fernández de Kirchner

[16 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @unutbu. Excellent answer and it clarified more than one fuzzy issue for me. Cheers

Comment: How to save the same problem when we save the values into a list and we need to print the list. I'd like to see the right chars.

Comment: @Sigur: Printing a list causes Python to print brackets around the *repr* of the items in the list separated by commas. If you want the `str` of the items, you need to [compose that yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32849250/190597). You might also need to decode bytes if the objects in your list are `bytes`, not (Python3) `str`s. If this explanation and the link do not fully answer your question, please open a new question with all the details (an example snippet of your list and the desired output).

Comment: @unutbu, thanks. The link is very useful. Off topic: everytime I read your nick I red as `ubuntu`. lol