# Python: UnicodeDecodeError using pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ascii, xlsx

```
import pandas as pd

msf=pd.read_excel('‪C:\Users\pauldufosse\Documents\TESTDANIEL.xlsx', has_index_names=True)
```

I'm having difficulties importing this xlsx document.

I will give you the full traceback as you might help me to find WHERE the wrong byte is.
I'm french so there is the character 'à' but I think this one is taken in charge by ascii/utf-8 am i right?

> runfile('C:/Users/pauldufosse/Documents/MSF.py', wdir='C:/Users/pauldufosse/Documents')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3052, in run_code
>       self.showtraceback()
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1851, in showtraceback
>       value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1240, in structured_traceback
>       self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1157, in structured_traceback
>       self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 509, in structured_traceback
>       out_list.extend(self._format_list(elist))
>
> File "C:\Users\pauldufosse\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 547, in _format_list
>       item += '    %s\n' % line.strip()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: We will need to see the file.

Answer (score 0):

That unicode conversion problem in `ultratb` is obscuring whatever the original exception was that `ultratb` is trying to display.

Judging by the [examples around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594878/pandas-dataframe-and-character-encoding-when-reading-excel-file), you can tell `pandas.read_excel` what encoding to use by passing e.g. `encoding="utf-8"` as you would with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).