# How to merge all csv files in a folder to single csv ased on columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a folder with multiple csv files with different column lengths

Have to merge them into single csv file using python pandas with printing file name as one column.

Input: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mbgjtrr6t069w1/AADC3ZrRZf33QBil63m1mxz_a?dl=0

Output:

```
Id  Snack      Price    SheetName
5   Orange      55     Sheet1
7   Apple       53     Sheet1
8   Muskmelon   33     Sheet1
11  Orange             Sheet2
12  Green Apple        Sheet2
13  Muskmelon          Sheet2
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: @jezrael yes will do

Comment: @jezrael can you check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
files = glob.glob('files/*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp).assign(SheetName=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   Id  Price SheetName        Snack
0  11    NaN   Sheet 2       Orange
1  12    NaN   Sheet 2  Green Apple
2  13    NaN   Sheet 2    Muskmelon
3   5   55.0    Sheet1       Orange
4   7   53.0    Sheet1        Apple
5   8   33.0    Sheet1    Muskmelon
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = []
for fp in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fp).assign(SheetName=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0])
    #another code
    dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: can you make column names to lower as there are duplicate columns.

Comment: @panda - not sure if understand, do you think duplicated columns names like `Snack, Snack, Id, Price, SheetName` ?

Comment: I mean Snack,snack

Comment: So convert all the column names into lower

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()`

Comment: No I mean do this on processing the sheet itself not renaming after done

Comment: I am getting this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @panda - hard question, because data dependent problem, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48647122), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33819765), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31558994)